# Como fazer Python entender formato Ano-Dia-Mês

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

A base de dados que estou trabalhando possui a coluna "Start Date" com o formato Ano-Dia-Mês. Já li e vi perguntas semelhantes mas mesmo assim não estou conseguindo informar ao Python esse formato. O que mais vi de solução e testei no meu código foi:

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'],format='%Y-%d-%b')
```

Mesmo depois disso o formato que o Python entende meus dados é Ano-Mês-Dia.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você utilizando o "strftime" você consiga formatar e interpretar.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> data_hoje = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(data_hoje)
2021-11-28 14:43:46.019650
```

Agr converta o formato da data que deseja

```
>>> data_hoje.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'28/11/2021'
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não entendi como fazer isso para alterar os dados de datas de uma coluna inteira. Tentei também:                                                                           
df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%b') , o código roda mas mesmo assim ele continua entendendo o 2019-02-01, que deveria ser 2019-02-Jan, como 2019-Fev-01.

Comment: O que já tentei:  df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format = '%y-%d-%b'),  df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%y/%d/%b')),  df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%y-%d-%b'),  df['Start Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].astype(str), format='%Y/%d/%m')

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com o seguinte:

```py
df['Start Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m')
df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%b')
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu não entendi exatamente como funciona, mas aparentemente ele tem algo que impede a formatação do mês do jeito que você precisa, caso seja separado pela "/".

`import datetime data_hoje = datetime.datetime.now() data_agora = data_hoje.strftime('%d.%b.%Y') print(data_agora)`

resultado 01.Dec.2021

Dependendo do seu uso, você pode fazer a alteração utilizando o replace, porém observando que ele irá perder o atributo "data".

`import datetime data_hoje = datetime.datetime.now() data_agora = data_hoje.strftime('%d.%b.%Y') data_nova = data_agora.replace('.','/') print(data_agora) print(data_nova)`